# Does ?assertException actually work with gen_fsm:startlink?

Tags: unit-testing, erlang

I have the following init method in a gen_fsm callback module (my_fsm):

```
init(Args) when length(Args) =:= 2 ->
   % do work with Args here
   {ok, my_state, InitialState}.
```

There is no other init-method in the callback module.

I want to write a unit test using eunit where I assert that calling gen_fsm with an argument-list that does not contain two elements fails:

```
start_link_without_args_exits_test() ->
   ?assertException(exit, _, gen_fsm:start_link(my_fsm, [], [])).
```

However, when the test is run, eunit skips the test with the message:

```
undefined
*unexpected termination of test process*
::{function_clause,[{my_fsm,init,[[]]},
                    {gen_fsm,init_it,6},
                    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Why is it that the test does not "catch" this error and reports it as a passed test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception actually happens in the `gen_fsm` process. When the call to the `init/1` function is made, `gen_fsm` catches the result. If it sees something like an error, it will send the error back to the parent (through `proc_lib:init_ack/1-2`) and then call `exit(Error)`.

Because you use `start_link` and are not trapping exit, you will never receive the return value -- you'll simply crash instead. For your test case, you'll need to either use `start` or call `process_flag(trap_exit,true)` in order to obtain the return value rather than just crashing when the other process goes down.

Then you'll need to switch from

```
?assertException(exit, _, gen_fsm:start_link(my_fsm, [], [])).
```

to something like

```
?assertMatch({error,{function_clause,[{my_fsm,init,_} | _]}}, 
             gen_fsm:start_link(my_fsm, [], []))
```

In order to have it working well.